# Find date difference of a specific date from a date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
policy.Exposure.fillna(pd.to_datetime(2016,12,31) - policy.EnrollDate,inplace=True)
```

I want to fill the missing value of my Exposure column with the day difference of 2016,12,31 - EnrollDate column. How should I write this?

All similar questions are subtracting one column from another column, not from a specific date.
[image]

I created a Exposure column with CancelDate - EnrollDate. Then since there are rows where CancelDate is NaT, I have columns in Expousre as NaN. So I am trying to fill the missing values in the exposure column with 2016,12,31 - EnrollDate. Then convert values in the column to float by

```
policy['Exposure'] = policy.Exposure.dt.days
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Such as adding conditional :
if CancelDate.notnull(): Exposure = CancelDate - Enroll
else: Exposure = 2016-12-31 - Enroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fill those `NaT` values with `pd.Series.fillna` and *then* subtract.

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2016/12/31', format='%Y/%m/%d')
policy['Exposure'] = (policy.CancelDate.fillna(dt) - policy.EnrollDate).dt.days
```

Comment: Hi, the difference looks like this : 191462400000000000  while I want it as a number of days(data type: timedelta)

Comment: @Dylan Can you please output about 10 rows of your data frame in your question? I need to know what format `policy.EnrollDate` is in.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved, I just realized I used dt.days myself.  But I think what I am doing can be simplified. Is there a way to do this better?

Comment: I mean not just Filling NaNs, I updated what I was doing in the original question, maybe we can skip the fillna step if we generate the Exposure column with condition.

Comment: @Dylan Sorry... didn't see that. yes! There is a simpler way. Check my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have considered this method before, but I was thinking "I don't want to change the CancelDate column". After reading your answer I realized that I don't have to fill the column "Inplace" thus it is OK. Thank you!

Comment: @Dylan Glad to help!